# Object extension in java

Tags: java, generics, class-hierarchy

In java if you have an object that requires a generic to extends a particular class, but you want to implement it with an extension of that class is there any way to let java know that you are not actually breaking your own rules? Example code below in the assumption that that made no sense.

```
public interface WantedInterface extends StaticInterface<WantedObject>

public class WantedObject extends OlderObject

public class OlderObject extends UsefulObject

public interface StaticInterface<T extends UsefulObject>
```

So my question is essentially, is there any way for me to tell my StaticInterface that my WantedObject does in fact extend my UsefulObject even though it is not direct? I would really prefer not to have to rewrite my WantedObject as a pure extension of a UsefulObject just because the OlderObject contains a lot of useful code and I am writing to a database where the sequence I am using would want to have knowledge of the current state of OlderObject. I realized in writing this that I could just have WantedInterface directly extend the interface for OlderObject, but I want to know if there is a way to avoid this.

EDIT:
Okay so, in a very weird twist of things I was able to fix the problem by changing the extension of WantedObject to UsefulObject, and then changing it back as it was. Perhaps the problem was just some temporary IDE thing? I'm using eclipse, does it have problems with this by chance?

Comment: It will know when it builds the tree.

Comment: What problem or error did you get? Because this should just work.

Comment: It said that WantedObject violated the requirement of StaticInterface to extend UsefulObject, but it seemed to pick up on things once I walked it through the hierarchy, which I find very odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A extends B` is [*transitive*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), which is a fancy way of saying that if `A extends B` and `B extends C`, then `A extends C` as well. For example, the compiler will have no problems with the following code:

```
UsefulObject uo = new WantedObject();
```

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Do you mean that Eclipse shows something is a bug, but the code still compiles? I've seen Eclipse not reacting to changes in my source code as fast as I wish it would, but a clean rebuild would usually fix things for me.

Comment: It wouldn't compile when I first tried it, but when I stepped through the object progression it compiled with no problems.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus if you could make it compile without changing your code, it's almost certainly an Eclipse thing (changing your code and then changing it back does not count as a real change: it's just a little trick that updates the timestamp of your file, which tells the IDE to invalidate its cache for the file, and tells the build system to re-compile the source).

Comment: Alright cool, good to know. Thank you so much for the knowledge bombs!

Comment: Please give a full example.